# The multi-part identifier not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure why the following is not working:

```
SELECT Menus.Id, MealTimes.Id, 
  Menus.MealTime_Id, CAST(MealTimes.Name AS TEXT) as MName, 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Menus.Date, 126) as Date, 
  CAST(Dishes.Name AS TEXT) as Name 
FROM C 
JOIN Menus 
  ON Menus.MealTime_Id=MealTimes.Id 
JOIN MenuDish 
  ON MenuDish.Menus_Id=Menus.Id 
JOIN Dishes 
  ON Dishes.Id=MenuDish.Dishes_Id 
WHERE C.Id=110 AND Menus.Date BETWEEN "2013-01-21" AND "2013-01-25"
```

It's now throwing the following error:

The multi-part identifier "MealTimes.Name" could not be bound.

My joins are basically like this:

```
$this->db->join('Menus', 'Menus.MealTime_Id=MealTimes.Id');
    $this->db->join('MenuDish', 'MenuDish.Menus_Id=Menus.Id');  
    $this->db->join('Dishes', 'Dishes.Id=MenuDish.Dishes_Id');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no table called `MealTimes` in your `FROM` or any of the joins.

Comment: You don't have a table or alias called `MealTimes`. So there is nothing to reference as `MealTimes.Name`

Comment: where is your `MealTime` table?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help other visitors to Stack Overflow in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You hasn't `MealTimes` table/alias in your query.

Comment: I had to add an additional JOIN. Solved the problem. Where clause was failing otherwise.